# Creating A Custom Made Online MCQ Quiz Using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I would like to create custom-made MCQ(only one correct answer) online quiz displaying only one question per page. Here is my database set up for the quiz.

(1) QuestionBankTable

```
|QuestionID|QuestionText|
|2|What is the HTTP port number?|
```

Objectives of this table is to

~Enter(new) and edit(current) questions

~Select and display the questions.

(2) OptionsTable

```
|AnswerID|QuestionID|AnswerText|
|21|2|80|
|22|2|53|
|23|2|8080|
|24|2|1278|
```

Objectives of this table is to

~Enter(new) and edit(current) options to each of the question

~Select and display the options of each question.

(3) AnswerSheetTable

```
|QuestionID|AnswerID|     
|2|21|
```

Objectives of this table is to

~Store the respective correct answer to the respective question.

(4) AnswerScriptsTable

```
|StudentID|(QuestionID)1|(QuestionID)2|
|S678|(AnswerID)13|(AnswerID)21|
```

Objectives of this table is to

~Store the respective answer given by the student to each of the corresponding questions.

~This will later be used to compare against the `AnswerSheetTable` to determine the number of correction answers and give the marks according in a PHP script.

=================================================================================

The main core of this quiz relies heavily on the PHP scripting.

```
|WebBrowser(HTML)|
|PHP Scripts|
|MySQL Database|
```

I have read up on the basic php/html/SQL tutorials but I need guidance on how should I go about `PLANNING` & `ORGANIZATION` the structure of the PHP scripts to provide an Optimal output of the quiz?

For example.

(1)The names of the necessary PHP scripts and their specific functions inside the script.

(P.S. I would like to display only one question per page with the option of navigating to the next or the previous question.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create the following scripts:

- config.php - use define() to setup database name. password, etc from one place
- common.php - encapsulate sql database, etc.
- html.php - for templating the html pages 
  eg. Create a class htmlPage
- user.php - Student login/registration management, etc
- quiz.php - for picking a question, its answers and the correct answer, sql queries for updating student response, etc. 
  eg. create a class question
- report.php - For displaying stats for the student
  Read data from sql and process accordingly
- admin.php - Adding, editing quetions/answers

This is only a basic idea and as the development proceeds, more files may be needed.

Answer (score 0):

As it sounds like you are fairly new to PHP, I would recommend you use one of the frameworks out there. It will do much of the heavy lifting for you and start getting you used to programming in PHP and other related concepts (MVC, OO etc). It will also provide you with a basic structure for your app that you can build on. If you try and come up with a structure yourself, you will almost certainly make mistakes that will cost you later on (I speak from the experience of having made most of those mistakes in the past). There are a whole host of frameworks out there (CodeIgniter, Yii, Kohana, Zend, Symfony2, Kohana etc). Personally I'd recommend Symfony2 as it comes with templating/views (Twig) and database/ORM (Doctrine) "out of the box" but that's just my recommendation.

Of course, if this is a homework question and you do need to come up with your own structure as part of it, then all bets are off!